# Search by the first match letters in word Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How to search result in Grails by the first match letters in word in Grails?
For example such query: `findBy...("Moscow")` must be have output: "mosquite", "moschino", etc.

Comment: You can do it using findBy..Like 
e.g Post.findByTitleLike("${queryString[0..n]}%") where n => number of characters you want to be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do here is easy if the scope is ***very*** narrow.  If you only want to search the first N matching chars - you could use the `findBy[domainClass]Like`.  You can find the documentation [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html).

An example would be something like this:

```
def size = params.query.size();
def results = Thing.findByNameLike("${params.query[0..size]}%") // search by length of query
```

**However, this is most likely way to narrow for what you're really looking to do.**  It may get you started but, if you want to get serious about search you need additional tools.  Take a look at the Searchable plugin located [here](https://grails.org/plugin/searchable).  It uses the [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/index.html) engine which is an amazing tool and possibly the best way to do text based search in your domain.

Good luck!